# Appium android settings

Tags: android, ui-automation, appium

I am unable to test a simple app on device using `Appium` as I get an error shown below. The weirdest thing something similar to this error is also shown when not connecting device. I am struck at this place from a very long time. I have done all the pre-conditions required for this. I have attached the images for android settings in `Appium` tool as well so please help me!
The code is

```
package com.sasken;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AppiumTestingApp {
    private AndroidDriver driver ;

@Before
public void setup() {

    String apk_Path = System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/APKfile/TestedAndroidApp.apk";

    //  File appDir = new File("..//TestedAndroidApp//bin//");
    //File app = new File(appDir, "TestedAndroidApp.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.0.2");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, apk_Path);             
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "ZX1D63HD35");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.sasken");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "MainActivity");
    //capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityConstants.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void appiumExampleTest() throws Exception {
    // find button with label or content-description "Button 1"
    //  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.name("Hello World!")));
    WebElement button=driver.findElement(By.name("Button1"));
    //  System.out.println("button:"+button);

    // click on button and start second Activity
    button.click();

    // we are on second screen now
    // check if second screen contains TextView with text “Activity2”
    driver.findElement(By.name("Activity2"));

    // click back button
    HashMap<String, Integer> keycode = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    keycode.put("keycode", 4);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", keycode);

    // we are again in main activity
    driver.findElement(By.name("Button1"));
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

}

The error is as given below

```
[TestNG] Running:
C:\Users\zamir\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1778615093\testng-    
customsuite.xml

FAILED: appiumExampleTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at   
com.sasken.AppiumTestingApp.appiumExampleTest(AppiumTestingApp.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
  Default test
  Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@3c03e1: 171 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@53c155: 77 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 34 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@14cda3: 10 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1ffba4f: 96 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@608423: 8 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Also,I would recommend to place the following method in your base class and then use it everywhere in order to perform Back action:

```
    public void clickBack(){
        driver.sendKeyEvent(4);
}
```

Comment: Hey Jean-Pierre....Same issue still exists...I have changed the driver from private to protected static but it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Use Instead

```
 capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.0.2");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, apk_Path);             
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "ZX1D63HD35");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.sasken");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "MainActivity");
```

Try this code :

```
    capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","emulator-5554");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score -1):

Java client 3.2.0, appium 1.4.8

Use this code for back action:

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```